# Preview is not available in sharing to Facebook with Firebase Dynamic Link

Tags: facebook, firebase-dynamic-links, android-sharing

I have created a shorten dynamic link with Firebase. When I share the link to Facebook, the preview is not available. I have tried with the long link. It's not working either. I have provided the link with metadata. But is is not showing the preview.
This is the code I am using now.

```
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLongLink(Uri.parse(longLink))
            .setIosParameters(new DynamicLink.IosParameters.Builder(getPackageName()).build())
            .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder(getPackageName()).build())
            .setSocialMetaTagParameters(
                    new DynamicLink.SocialMetaTagParameters.Builder()
                            .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(demoPhoto))
                            .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(itemsVO.getThumbnail().get(0)))
                            .build())
            .buildShortDynamicLink(ShortDynamicLink.Suffix.SHORT)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Short link created
                    Uri shortLink = task.getResult().getShortLink();
                    itemsVO.setShareLink(shortLink.toString()+"?d=1");
                    shareBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    // Error
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error in creating dynamic link", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // ...
                    shareBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
```

Can anyone tell me why it is not working?

Comment: Do the meta tags get rendered server-side?

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: I had assumed you _knew_, it being your code … Either check the source code when you call that URL in your browser, or see what the Facebook debug tool has to say.

Comment: ok. I am on it.

Comment: Did you find a solution?